# Cholesky Decomposition (mathematical understanding)

Tags: python, math, matrix

So I don't understand why mutiplying a matrix with random numbers by upper cholesky decomposition matrix gives a matrix with correlation.

For example,

```
from scipy.linalg import cholesky
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

corr_mat = np.array([[1, 0.5], 
                     [0.5, 1]])

upper_chol = cholesky(corr_mat)
lower_chol = cholesky(corr_mat, lower = True)

random_num = np.random.normal(0,1, size=(10**5,2))
ans = random_num @ upper_chol
pearsonr(ans[:,0], ans[:,1])
```

The result is 0.5 which I intended. But I just don't understand mathematically how this works.

Answer (score 0):

This article will give you information about the mathematical understanding it also has geometric representation how this works. ([See article here](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/02/08/use-the-cholesky-transformation-to-correlate-and-uncorrelate-variables.html))